# Qt animation without interpolation

Tags: qt, animation, interpolation

is it possible to deactivate the interpolation of the QGraphicsItemAnimation? i need a rectangle to "jump" between two positions, but i cannot use a QTimer due to the construction of the other classes, so the only thing that seems to work is an animation.

Comment: That class is deprecated... are you stuck on Qt 4.2 for some reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the idea of using this class from here: [Smooth animations with QGraphicsScene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533499/smooth-animations-with-qgraphicsscene)

now that i know it is deprecated i figured using QPropertyAnimation combined with QSequentialAnimationGroup is doing the trick. by using animation duration of 0 and adding pause to the animation group i get a "jump"